# Why does react profiler indicates a component rerendered due to parent, but no parent shows as rendered

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to debug React component's re-rerendering and not understanding a flame chart.
My component `HorizonalNav` says it was re-rendered due to parent re-rendering, but no parent component in the tree indicates it was re-rendered.

How do I figure out what really caused the re-render ?

[image]